# Calculating integral of function with square root

Tags: calculus, integration

I don't have any idea how to calculate this integral.
I learned to calculate the elementary functions, and how to calculate by the positioning way.

For example $t=e^x+1  \rightarrow dt=e^x \, dx$ and then solving as usual.
I having trouble with this:

$\int \sqrt{e^x+1} \, dx$ and $\sqrt{e^x-1} \, dx$ but I guess it's very similar.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When we integrate an expression involving a square root expression $\sqrt{A}$, letting the radicand $A$ be the square of another variable sometimes works. For example, in your case, let $u^2 = e^x+1$. Then $$x = \ln(u^2-1) = \ln\big((u-1)(u+1)\big) = \ln(u-1)+\ln(u+1)$$ so that $$dx = \bigg(\frac{1}{u-1}+\frac{1}{u+1}\bigg)du.$$
Hence
$$
\int \sqrt{e^x+1}\,dx=\int\sqrt{u^2}\bigg(\frac{1}{u-1}+\frac{1}{u+1}\bigg)du =\int \bigg(\frac{u}{u-1}+\frac{u}{u+1}\bigg)du.
$$
You should be able to finish off the problem from here.

The same method turns out to work for the second integral, but the outcome is not so similar. Let $z^2=e^x-1$. Then
$x=\ln(z^2+1)$, so that $\displaystyle dx = \frac{2z}{z^2+1}dz$. Hence
$$
\int \sqrt{e^x-1}\,dx=\int\sqrt{z^2}\frac{2z}{z^2+1}dz = 2\int\frac{z^2}{z^2+1}dz = 2\int\bigg(1-\frac{1}{z^2+1}\bigg)dz.
$$

Comment: Excellent answer! (+1)

Answer (score 5):

Define $\displaystyle u=\sqrt{e^x+1} \rightarrow \frac{du}{dx}=\frac{e^x}{2 \sqrt{e^x+1}}=\frac{e^x}{2u} \rightarrow dx=\frac{du\cdot{2u}}{e^x}=\frac{du\cdot{2u}}{u^2-1}$.

Do you know how to proceed?

Hint: $\displaystyle \frac{2u^2}{u^2-1}=2+\frac{2}{u^2-1}$. Does this help?

Comment: No. It's my first calculus course and I don't even know this way of solving it. Any other ideas?

Comment: Why other idea is needed? It is integration by substitution and from your post it seems that you have learned it.

Comment: Please see my edited post.

Comment: Yes. but dealing with the fraction and the algebra got me a little bit confused. Well I am not so good in calculus.

Comment: @Galc127 Your last line (hint) I wouldn't recommend to someone starting a calculus course (as it requires a hyperbolic substitution). I'd recommend the substitution $t=u^2-1.$

Comment: @alexqwx, $\displaystyle \frac{2}{u^2-1}=\frac{1}{u-1}-\frac{1}{u+1}$, no substitutions at all. And, yes, I assume that he/she learned about partial fractions.

Comment: @Galc127 Well, why don't you recommend this simpler substitution, then?

Comment: I won't recommend it because it isn't simpler.

Comment: @Galc127 Yes, it is. Your first hint requires a hyperbolic substitution, whereas my hint requires only standard substitution (which is assumed as the OP can't do the integration without substitution).

Comment: We got $\displaystyle \int \frac{2u^2}{u^2-1} du$. Setting $u^2-1=t$ I will get $\displaystyle \int \frac{\sqrt{t+1}}{t}dt$. How is it simpler than using partial fractions?

Comment: Ah, yes. Never mind, then.